# Solve this particular optimisation problem

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, economics

Can anyone help answer the below? I know I'm supposed to use the envelope theorem i.e. find the value function then differentiate wrt $p$<sub>$x$</sub> and $p$<sub>$y$</sub>, but I'm struggling to get the right answer. Thank you in advance!

A firm uses input $x$ to produce $y = f(x)$ while facing market prices $(p$<sub>$x$</sub>, $p$<sub>$y$</sub>) for $(x, y)$, respectively.
The choice of $x$ satisfies the first order condition for profit maximisation, $p$<sub>$y$</sub>$f′(x) − p_x = 0$.

If the prices change by the small amounts $(p$<sub>$x$</sub>,$p$<sub>$y$</sub>), what is the approximate change in the optimal use of $x$?

Comment: The first-order condition implicitly defines $x$ as a function of $(p_x,p_y)$. You need to use the implicit function theorem (implicit differentiation) to find the partial derivatives of the optimal choice of $x$.

Comment: thank you for the answer but i'm still not getting it - could you possibly be a bit more explicit? I don't fully understand what I am trying to differentiate with respect to, and this makes it difficult for me to know how to use the implicit function theorem in this context

Answer (score 0):

The first-order condition for profit maximization is
$$F(p_x,p_y,x)=p_yf'(x) − p_x = 0$$

The implicit function theorem tells us that as long as $F$ is continuously differentiable, and $F_x\neq 0$ then the partial derivatives of $x$ are given by
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial p_x}=-\frac{F_{p_x}}{F_x}\text{ and } \frac{\partial x}{\partial p_y}=-\frac{F_{p_y}}{F_x}$$

---

The partial derivatives you get above are the same as you would get from using the chain rule to implicitly differentiate the following with respect to $p_x$ and $p_y$
$$p_yf'[x(p_x,p_y)] − p_x = 0$$

---

Hopefully, you should be able to take it from there using either method.

Comment: thank you for this!